# Reading an XML from a webservice to a datagrid, but can´t fill the Kendogrid with the values

Tags: c#, json, xml-serialization, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I want to try using kendo grid.i have place following css and js files

```
<link href="../Content/kendo/2014.1.318/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../Content/kendo/2014.1.318/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/kendo/2014.1.318/kendo.web.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

i have my htm as

```
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({

          dataSource: {
              transport: {
                  read: { url: "AssetTransfer_Services/TransferRequest.asmx/BindKendoCreatedGrid", dataType: "xml",
                      data: { status: 'RequestState' }
                  }
              },
              pageSize: 20
          },
          pageable: {
              refresh: true,
              pageSizes: true,
              buttonCount: 8
          },
                        columns: [

                                {
                                    field: "TransferRequestId",
                                    title: "Request Id"
                                },
                                {
                                    field: "AssetId",
                                    title: "Asset Id"
                                }
                               ]
      });
```

and my cs as

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string BindCreatedGrid(string status)
{
    Login l = new Login();
    long userId = l.UserId;

    if (userId != 0)
    {
        TransferRequestMethods trm = new TransferRequestMethods();
        status = GetStatus(status);
        DataSet dsResult = trm.GetCreatedHardwareTransferRequestList(status, userId);
        return dsResult.GetXml();
    }
    else
    {
        return "Expired";
    }
}
```

value is getting returned to kendogrid but its not binding any value.i dont know whether it should b converted to json or how to do it.

Comment: What is the structure of your xml that you are trying to bind to the grid? When mapping to the xml source you need to provide the required xpath to the element/attribute you want to bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question(Thanks to Vishnu :) ).
I donno know whether this ts the right method but it worked for me..

first in my cs i returned xml as string..

```
 public string BindCreatedGrid(string status)
{
    Login l = new Login();
    long userId = l.UserId;

    if (userId != 0)
    {
        TransferRequestMethods trm = new TransferRequestMethods();
        status = GetStatus(status);
        DataSet dsResult = trm.GetCreatedHardwareTransferRequestList(status, userId);
        string s =dsResult.GetXml();
        return s;
    }
    else
    {
        return "Expired";
    }
}
```

then in html i gave as..

```
   var data = "";
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "../Transfer/Transfer_Services/Transfer.asmx/BindCreatedGrid",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          data: JSON.stringify({ status: 'RequestState' }),
          success: function (result) {
              debugger;

              data = result.d;
              $("#grid").kendoGrid({

                  dataSource: {
                      transport: {

                          read: function (options) {
                              options.success(data);
                          }
                      },
                      schema: {
                          type: "xml",
                          data: "/NewDataSet/myTable",
                          model: {
                              // configure the fields of the object                                  
                              fields: {
                                  // the "title" field is mapped to the text of the "title" XML element
                                  TransferId: "TransferId/text()",
                                  // the "title" field is mapped to the text of the "title" XML element
                                  AssetId: "AssetId/text()",
                                  // the "title" field is mapped to the text of the "title" XML element
                                  AssetName: "AssetName/text()",
                                  // the "title" field is mapped to the text of the "title" XML element
                                  DMName: "DMName/text()",
                                  // the "title" field is mapped to the text of the "title" XML element
                                  ToUser: "ToUser/text()",
                                  // the "title" field is mapped to the text of the "title" XML element
                                  Status: "Status/text()",
                                  // the "title" field is mapped to the text of the "title" XML element
                                  Details: "Details/text()",
                                  // the "title" field is mapped to the text of the "title" XML element
                                  Verify: "Verify/text()",
                                  // the "title" field is mapped to the text of the "title" XML element
                                  Delete: "Delete/text()"

                              }
                          }
                      },
                      pageSize: 20
                  },
                  sortable: true,
                  filterable: true,
                  reorderable: true,
                  navigatable: true,
                  selectable: "multiple",
                  columnMenu: true,
                  resizable: true,
                  pageable: {
                      refresh: true,
                      pageSizes: true,
                      buttonCount: 8
                  },
                  columns: [
                            {
                                field: "TransferRequestId",
                                title: "Request Id"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "AssetId",
                                title: "Asset Id"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "AssetName",
                                title: "Asset Name"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "DMName",
                                title: "DM Name"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "ToUserName",
                                title: "To User"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "StatusName",
                                title: "Status"
                            },
                            {
                                field: "Details",
                                title: "Details",
                                template: kendo.template($("#ActionLinkDetails").html())

                            },
                            {
                                field: "Verify",
                                title: "Verify",
                                template: kendo.template($("#ActionLinkVerify").html())
                            },
                            {
                                field: "Delete",
                                title: "Delete",
                                template: kendo.template($("#ActionLinkDelete").html())
                            }
                            ]
              });
              // options.success(result);                
          }
```

It worked for me .. is there any other way ? any new method appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I've been working with kendo not for too long but I had a similar trouble, so what I did is define the schema in the datasource and after that the binding worked :)

Comment: it would be helpful if u can share ur code for datasource